# Is the $\infty$ symbol used in limits an actual mathematical object, or just notation?

Tags: calculus, limits

My calculus textbook uses $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = \infty$$ to express an infinite limit.

Does this mean that the expression $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ is the same as some mathematical entity symbolized by $\infty$, or is it just notation used to condense meaning? Also, is this notation really correct/proper (is it used in formal contexts) or is my textbook breaking formality for the sake of learning?

Comment: You can make this notation completely rigorous by adding an element $\infty$ to the topological space $\mathbb R$ that satisfies $\infty>r$ for all $r\in\mathbb R$ by assumption. But you can also treat it as short-hand for $$\forall y\in\mathbb R:\exists x \in\mathbb R: \forall z>x: f(z)>y$$

Comment: What is "a mathematical object"?  What properties do "mathematical objects" have?  Is $2$ "just notation" (used to represent the successor of the successor of some initial object), or is it a "mathematical object"?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Rather ...$\forall z \in (c-x, c+x): f(z) > y$, given we consider $\lim_{x \rightarrow c}$, not $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}$.

Comment: There is a such thing as the "extended real line" $\overline R=[-\infty,\infty]$ in which we take the conventions $0\cdot\infty = 0\cdot-\infty = 0$ and $\infty-\infty$ undefined.

Comment: It *may* be either in context.  But in the context of limits it is a notation and *not* a number.  $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = \infty$ has a specific meaning as to the behavior of $f(x)$.  ... Hmm, interesting, it has a specific meaning in $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = M$ as well, but now that I think about it I've never seen a class or a text formally define that.

Comment: It's a great question.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number , no matter how we try to define it. It is just a concept we need to deal with limits or cardinalities. So, strictly speaking the notation is sloppy and not rigorous, but this is usually ignored , so that this notation is often used nevertheless. The "extended real line" does not let vanish the issues with $\infty$

Comment: If you add the extended number lines I think you need to define what $\infty - k$ and $\infty -k < m$ means so that our definitions of $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=M$ and $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = \infty$ mean in regards to delta epsilon proof.

Comment: @Peter $\infty$ is not a number ever, but it can be an object.  But it *isn't* in the definition of limits.  In the def of limits it's notation for a concept and doesn't resemble a number at all. And the notation is *not* sloppy.  $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) =\infty$ means for any real $M$ we can find a real positive $\delta$ so that whenever $|x-c|<\delta$ then $f(x) > M$.  Nothing sloppy about that.  What is sloppy is how most of us *think* of it as meaning $f(x)$ "goes to" infinity. (And making $\infty$ an object requires great care...as you say, the issues do not go away.)

Comment: @fleablood To be honest, it feels weird to me that we use the equal sign when we don't actually mean that two things are equal to each other

Comment: @hawexp This notation distinguishes the case that the values eventually go beyond every finite (positive) limit from the other case of a not existing limit, namely that the sequence "oscillates" (easiest example $(-1)^n$). In German , sequences with limit $\infty$ or $-\infty$ are called "bestimmt divergent", I do not know how it is called in English.

Comment: @hawexp  That is an *incredibly* valid point.  We really shouldn't.  In theory when we define $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = M$ we are *not* defining any number but a property that $f(x)$ has.  However that $M$ *is* a value and that value has a significant meaning in terms of the limit.  I guess to be formal we distinguish between $f(x)\to M$ (behavior) and $\lim(f(x))$ (a value that is equal to $M$) and $f(x)\to \infty$ would mean there is no value of $\lim(f(x))$...  okay, it's a *little* sloppy....

Comment: @fleablood Is there a reason mathematicians don't change the notation so that it's more accurate?

Comment: I do not know.  I imagine they prefer the flexibility.

Comment: Mathematics is stuck with a large number of inconsistent or illogical notations, bequeathed to us by tradition. This is one; how about the meaning of $\sin^{-1}$ versus $\sin^2$? Or the notation in Galois theory of $K/k$, now fortunately becoming disused?

Comment: For a person who is studying limits it is best keep the symbol $\infty$ as a part of notation. Equations and phrases containing this symbol are given a precise meaning via a somewhat complicated definition and there is nothing more to it. Thus every use of $\infty$ in equations and phrases in a book must be preceded by the corresponding definition. Otherwise its usual case of intellectual dishonesty.